# Python-Z3: Python's assertion is not holding

Tags: python, z3, assert, assertion, z3py

I wanted to test whether the `assert` statement holds for z3 results.

To do so, I test the following statement: `exists` an integer `x`, such that `for all` integers `y`, `(x>y)`. Which is false: there is no integer greater than the rest of the integers.

So I translate this to Z3py:

```
y_1 = Int('y_1')
x_1 = Int('x_1')
ttt = Tactic("qe")
w = Goal()
phi = Exists(x_1, ForAll (y_1, (x_1>y_1)))
w.add(phi)
result_ttt = ttt(w)
print(result_ttt)
```

As expected, the printed result is: `[[False]]`

So I test assert the following:

`assert [[False]] == result_ttt`

And, surprisingly, the result is `assertion error`!

Any help? Probably it has to do with the type of `result_ttt` being `<class 'z3.z3.ApplyResult'>` (after doing `type(result_ttt`).

---

Note that, analogously, if we choose a satisfiable statement the assertion does not hold either.

The chosen statement has been: `for all` integers `x`, `exists` integer `y`, `(x>y)`. Which is true. In this case, the result is `[[]]` (since quantifier elimination is satisfactory). And when doing `assert [[]] == result` the result is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```py
[[False]]
```

all that means is that you've a nested list with that element in it. Note that this has nothing to do with z3. It's a valid Python object.

Compare this to your `result_tt`, which is a `Goal`. So, you're trying to compare a `Goal` to a nested python list; and those two things are never going to be equal. They are completely different objects. Hence the assertion failure.

You're getting confused by the fact that these two things print the same way. But checking equality is an entirely different operation. If you really want to compare that they "print" the same, you can say something like:

```py
assert '[[False]]' == obj_to_string(result_ttt)
```

But of course that's very ugly and is fragile in case z3 developers decide to change how goals are converted to strings later on.

In general, you shouldn't be trying to compare goals to anything else, and instead use a solver to prove them, or tactics to transform and eliminate them. Using them in any other way will be fragile and will likely not do what you want in the first place to start with.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 1) Your solution works. 2) Your advice also works and it is a better solution. I have replaced the quantifier elimination by a solver, and then check if ```res == sat```, or ```res == unsat```

Comment: Checking against `sat`/`unsat` is the best way to go indeed. Good find.